# HighCharts image export

Tags: highcharts

I am using HighChart in my application.
I want to export chart image on a button click like http://jsfiddle.net/hfrntt/fXHB5/1896/.
but i want to save image in a predefined folder and remove the save dialog pop-up to save image.

On button click image saved on the predefined folder.(No save dialog)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to save the image in a predefined folder on the users computer?  This is not allowed due to security concerns.

Comment: I want to save image on the server on a predefined folder not on the client machine.

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup an exportserver. Upon the client sends the Highcharts SVG file to this service it will be converted to an image. Before the server returns the image to the client you can save it to the predefined filesystem.

Here you can find a php export server and a java based one. https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server developed by Highcharts

These exportservers are setup to remove the temporary created files. You have to change the code a bit to prevent this.

read also this article for more background information on [Highcharts exportservers](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to involve much more than simply using highcharts.  You are going to have to use some sort of wrapper that will actually render the chart/page on the server-side and then essentially output it as an image.  The following are links taken from a [post](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/42-highcharts-on-the-server) on the highcharts website.

[GWT Highcharts wrapper](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/)

[Highcharts-server-side-export](https://github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export) (with Rhino/Batik)