# Highcharts Export Server Configuration Settings

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts ([Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts)), just released an update to their offering with a bundled export server. This is to enable you to generate charts serverside and include them automatically in emails/pdfs/etc.

Their instructions on how to prepare this is: [Github instructions](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/java)

I'm running XAMPP on Mountain Lion. I have successfully built the war package and opened the demo page.

I am now preparing a war for the production environment (centOS 6). The production site is running the Yii framework.

1. What I do not understand, the variables that need to be configured:

   - app.properties = weburl
   - dev.properties = weburl
   - prod.properties = weburl

In a MVC framework environment (such as yii) what should these url's be?

2.After the war is created, the github tutorial says to upload this file. But, what other files are required? The entire exporting-server directory? If so, where on the server should these files be placed? Is the file location the url path that should be referenced in the weburl variables?

Greater clarification on how to setup/deploy the export server would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The created .war file should be uploaded to an Java application server, such as [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), Jboss, TC-server, [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/), etc.

It's not suitable to run in a PHP environment.

Comment: Gert, thanks for your reply. In the github file there is a php folder. https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server and on this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277039/highcharts-image-export you mention a php export server. Do you have any additional docs on how to use the php export server?

Comment: You find the php-servers here. https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/php/. Php-batik server is the stable one of the two, but lacks support for serverside generation of charts. Here you'll find the doc on how to setup http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use#exporting. The php-phantomjs is not found stable in production. The java server is the one, which we support and recommend.

Comment: Gert, I'm quite confused..this link [link](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts) and this [link](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/exporting-server/java/readme.md) I'm sure have the answer, but it seems to have a bit conflicting processes. I just finished reading Joe Kuan's **bold** Learning Highcharts **bold** and his solutions didn't seem to mesh with the above links...Are there any kb articles/blogs where you have a step by step explanation of the current endorsed method?

Comment: Just as a follow up, what I'm trying to do is generate the chart options with a php script, pass these chart options to the server to have the chart rendered as an svg, converted to a png, saved to a temporary file, then use mpdf to embed this temporary png file into a pdf report.